# How to swap Solana on devnet?

Tags: token, swap, solana, solana-web3js

I'm trying to make a swap **WSOL-USDC**, and I used this doc:
https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-sdk-V1-demo/blob/master/src/swapOnlyAmm.ts#L51

- In **mainnet** ✅ everything works fine
- In **devnet** ❌ I get this error :

  > Error: Unable to retrieve account information for ID 58oQChx4yWmvKdwLLZzBi4ChoCc2fqCUWBkwMihLYQo2

In the code I just replaced:

`const rpcUrl = 'https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com';`

with

`const rpcUrl = 'https://api.devnet.solana.com';`

**FYI the addresses I use:**

```
'SOL': new Currency(9, 'USDC', 'USDC'),
'WSOL': new Token(TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, new PublicKey('So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112'), 9, 'WSOL', 'WSOL'),
'USDC': new Token(TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, new PublicKey('EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v'), 6, 'USDC', 'USDC'),
    
const targetPool = '58oQChx4yWmvKdwLLZzBi4ChoCc2fqCUWBkwMihLYQo2';
```

**But I need to do something else to make it work in devnet?**

Answer (score 0):

The program might not exist on devnet (or might have a different program id), the pools might have different addresses, and the mints will all be different on devnet.

It's not just a matter of changing the rpc to devnet.